# Copy certain columns of one datatable to a new datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I've found similar question in visual basic, but nothing exact and in c#.

I want to copy certain columns (say 1, 4, and 5) using their INDEX (i.e. 1, 4, and 5 are the index and not their name/header) from a 10-column datatable and create an object (I think an array/list would be best?), that I will pass to form2. In form2 I'd like to create a new datatable from these arrays/lists, so it will end up having 3 columns that are identical to columns 1, 4, and 5 of the original datatable. I'd also like to have the option to delete the first element of each array before I pass it, based on a true/false value that I will set elsewhere.

Here's the outline I've got so far ('alldata' is my datatable, 'cx' is the xth column I want to get):

Form1:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //next
    {
        this.Hide();

        int c1 = 1; int c2 = 4; int c3 = 5
        int[] 1st_col; int[] 2nd_col; int[] 3rd_col;
        [assign c1th column to 1st_col, etc]

        if (variable = marker_number)
        {
            [delete first element of each array]
        }

        Form2 step2 = new Form2(1st_col, 2nd_col, 3rd_col);
        step2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2:

```
    public Form2(int 1st_col, int 2nd_col, int 3rd_col)
    {

        DataTable mytable1 = new DataTable();            
        [add 1st, 2nd, and 3rd cols to mytable1]
        InitializeComponent();


    }
```

If there's anything else I should provide, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Updated, try this:

Form1

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //10 column datatable
        var dt10 = new DataTable("DT10");
        dt10.Columns.Add("PKID");
        dt10.Columns.Add("FName"); 
        dt10.Columns.Add("MName");
        dt10.Columns.Add("LName");
        dt10.Columns.Add("Address");
        dt10.Columns.Add("City");
        dt10.Columns.Add("State");
        dt10.Columns.Add("Zip");
        dt10.Columns.Add("Phone");
        dt10.Columns.Add("Fax");

        //give some sample data
        dt10.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Matt", "James", "Smith", "123 Main", "Philadelphia", "PA", "12141", "215-555-1111", "215-555-1212" });
        dt10.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Mark", "James", "Smith", "123 Main", "Pittsburgh", "PA", "12141", "215-555-1111", "215-555-1212" });
        dt10.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Luke", "James", "Smith", "123 Main", "Scranton", "PA", "12141", "215-555-1111", "215-555-1212" });
        dt10.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "John", "James", "Smith", "123 Main", "Reading", "PA", "12141", "215-555-1111", "215-555-1212" });
        dt10.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Paul", "James", "Smith", "123 Main", "Harrisburg", "PA", "12141", "215-555-1111", "215-555-1212" });

        //create new datatable with subset of columns
        var dt3 = new DataTable("DT3");
        dt3.Columns.Add("FName");
        dt3.Columns.Add("LName");
        dt3.Columns.Add("Phone");

        //indexes can be hardcoded or set at runtime
        int c1 = 1; int c2 = 3; int c3 = 8;

        //add all rows, but only the specified columns
        foreach (DataRow r in dt10.Rows)
        {
            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { r[c1], r[c2], r[c3] } );                
        }

        bool includeFirstRow = chkIncludeFirstRow.Checked;
        if (!includeFirstRow)
        {
            dt3.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        Form2 step2 = new Form2(dt3);
        step2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(DataTable dt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //do your thing here, bind to datagridview or whatever

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, though first of all how do I properly initialize drc as I get the error "The type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' has no constructors defined". I have never had this problem before -- why does it not use default constructors? Also, what is "oneRow" supposed to be? I thought it meant something like "alldata[i]" but that yields an error that says I may apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'